Permeability of plastics to alcohol vapour
I was just wondering which plastics have the lowest permeability to alcohol vapour?
I am thinking about purchasing 70% isopropyl wipes for infrequent use around the home and worry that they may dry up in the packaging itself if the alcohol is able to evaporate through the plastic. The wipes I am thinking about buying are individually wrapped in sachets (like so). The sachets are much thinner than the canisters that the wipes typically come in (see here, for example).

Consider a bottle of isopropyl alcohol (those last a long long time) and paper towels.

You likely should be more concerned about the thickness of the container and the seal of the lid than the type of plastic.

It isn't the composition of the plastic in sachets that will make the difference here: it is whether they are treated to minimise vapour penetration (as they likely are). Many thin plastic food containers (like crisp packets) are not just, for example thin films of PET, they are also metallised to prevent atmospheric gas penetration. And many other thin coatings have similar effects making thin films much more robust to diffusion than even much thicker containers.
